# How to use ArgumentOutOfRangeException with multiple params?

Tags: c#, exception

I have the following code.

```
DoSomething(int min, int max)
{
    if (min < 1 || min > 5)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("min");
    if (max < 1 || max > 5)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("max");
    if (min > max)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("min & max");

    DoSomethingWithYourLife(); // =)
}
```

In the documentation I state that min and max must be on the [1-5] range, and max has to be greater or equal to min.

Is the third Exception correctly constructed? If not, how should I construct the Exception?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, the argument for the `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` constructor should always be one of the parameter names. You can pick either of them - I usually assume that the *earlier* parameter is correct, so the *later* parameter is incorrect in relation to it. You can (and should) give more information in the message though. It's also *really* handy if you give the actual value - so:

```
if (min < 1 || min > 5)
{
    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("min", min, "min must be between 1 and 5 inclusive");
}
if (max < 1 || max > 5)
{
    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("max", max, "max must be between 1 and 5 inclusive");
}
if (max < min)
{
    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("max", max, "max must not not be less than min");
}
```

For [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org), I have helper methods for this, such as:

```
internal static void CheckArgumentRange(string paramName,
    int value, int minInclusive, int maxInclusive)
{
    if (value < minInclusive || value > maxInclusive)
    {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(paramName, value,
            "Value should be in range [" + minInclusive + "-" + maxInclusive + "]");
    }
}
```

That way you could simplify the above to:

```
Preconditions.CheckArgumentRange("min", min, 1, 5);
Preconditions.CheckArgumentRange("max", max, 1, 5);
if (max < min)
{
    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("max", max, "max must not not be less than min");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd strongly recommend just picking one of them, but providing a more informative error message with [this overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wx2cdec8(v=vs.110).aspx) of the constructor:

```
if (min > max)
    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("max", "max must be greater than or equal to min");
```